# 4th category showing wrong url - wordpress. how can I solve this?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, post, categories

I am using my own theme for a blog.
It's working fine with some minor issues.

When I click the posts from a category it's redirected to the proper post under the correct url except 4th category post.

If I click any post from 4th category it's redirected to the proper post but under the wrong URL.

eg:

1. If I click the 2nd post of 4th category then it's showing the
   correct post but under the 1st post URL.
   www.mydomain.com/blog/post1
2. If I click the 3rd post of 4th category then it's showing the
   correct post but under the 2nd post URL.
   www.mydomain.com/blog/post2

why its happening?
here is my code.
any help will be very thank full.

```
    function get_blogroll(){
/*
post : return the blogroll in blog home page
*/  
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array('cat'=> 4, 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged );        
    query_posts( $args); 
    if(have_posts()) :
        print ('<div class="row">'); 
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();   
                $date = explode(",", get_the_time("F,j,Y", "", "", false));
                print('
                    <section class="large-4 columns">
                    <section class="main_post cbox1">
                    <section class="post_inner row collapse">');             
                    print('<div class="large-2 columns small-2">
                                <span class="date_format">
                                    <span class="date_num">' . $date[1] . '
                                    </span><br/><span class="date_month">' . substr($date[0], 0, 3) . '
                                    </span></span></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>');
                    print ('<div class="large-10 columns small-10">');
                            the_title('<a class="blogroll_title" href="' . get_permalink() . '"><h1 class="heading_blog">', '</h1></a>');
                    print ('</div>');                                   
                    print ('<!--end post_inner --></section>');
                    print ('<div class="row collapse post_content"><p>');
                        if (strlen(get_the_content()) > 100) {
                            $content = get_the_content();
                            echo str_replace('&nbsp;', '<br /><br />', substr($content, 0, 300)). "....";   
                            echo '</p><a href=" ' . get_permalink() . ' " class="read_more button button_top button_body_col11 button_radius">Read More</a>';
                        }
                        else { the_content(); echo "</p>"; }    
                    print ('<!--end post_content--></div>'>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've deleted those post and added those again then it's working very fine.
try that method.
that should work.

still my code is

```
     $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;


  $args = array('cat'=> 4, 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged );        
    query_posts( $args);
```

note : I did not change **'cat' => 4**

Comment: I've remove all 4th ctegory posts and add them back freshly.. and it's working fine.. weird.. thanks a lot...